# distinguie el numero de un input en php

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde le pido al usuario que ingrese un numero, despues de ingresarlo, se debe verificar que numero se ingreso e imprimir algo diferente para cada numero, la cuestion es que no tengo idea de como hacerlo

```
        <form method="POST" action="entrar.php">
        <h2>Digite el codigo del estadio para buscar los encuentros proximos</h2>
        Codigo:<input type ="input" name="codigo" placeholder="Digite el codigo" required>
         <input type="submit" value="INGRESAR">
        </form>


        <html>
$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("error al conectar");
mysqli_select_db ($conexion,"parcial")or die ("error al conectar");
        $consulta = mysqli_query ($conexion,"select * from local");
        $nfilas = mysqli_num_rows ($consulta); 
        if ($nfilas > 0){
        for ($i=0; $i<$nfilas; $i++){
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_array ($consulta);
           print "L-#" . $fila["codigo"];print " -- " . $fila["edad"]; print " -- " . $fila["nombre"];print "<br>";
        }
        }
    </html>
```

Comment: Necesitas una base de datos para dar el resultado?

Comment: Pues el número va a ingresar a una tabla llamada "estadio", allí verificará si el código del estadio existe, si existe va a mostrar los jugadores que llevarán a cabo el partido, hasta el momento el código que subí, no distingue el código del estadio por lo que siempre muestra los mismos datos sin importar el código

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer

Comment: El código que pusiste tiene una consulta a una base de datos, pero no esta si quiera entre las etiquetas correctas, <?php   ?>, te recomendaría documentarte mas antes de preguntar, para que puedas hacer una pregunta mas concreta.

Comment: ah si lo siento, es que en la parte del codigo donde estoy haciendo la consulta, hay php dentro del html por eso las etiquetas no estan, solo pase como lo mas importante

Comment: respecto a lo que quiero, lo tratare de explicar, voy a pedirle al usuario que ingrese un codigo de estadio, digamos 10, una vez se ingrese esto mostrara cuales partidos hay en ese estadio, ahora, si ingreso 11, la idea es que me muestre los datos de los partidos de otro estadio y no pueden ser los mismos que los del estadio 10